# compile command failed due to signal 9 Xcode 11 beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am unable to solve this bug since about 4-5 days... I am using Xcode 11 beta 1 and every time I run my app I am getting error 'Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code'

I have deleted the derived data. I have also tried removing all the pods and installing them again! i have tried running it on different iPhones simulators.

The error message I am getting is actually even longer than described below but I just look the important looking part of it and kept it here. this is (a part of) error message I am getting:

-I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf/Protobuf.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftMessages/SwiftMessages.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++/grpcpp.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core/grpc.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library/leveldb.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb/nanopb.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Desktop/someApp/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Desktop/someApp/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Desktop/someApp/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalyticsInterop -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Desktop/someApp/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuthInterop -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Desktop/someApp/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/someApp/Debug-iphonesimulator/someApp(Update).build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/someApp/Debug-iphonesimulator/someApp(Update).build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/someApp/Debug-iphonesimulator/someApp(Update).build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DGPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DPB_FIELD_32BIT=1 -Xcc -DPB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS=1 -Xcc -DPB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/kanishka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/someApp-ffkcnnipndtmimasqjahqhgwthxq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/someApp/Debug-iphonesimulator/someApp(Update).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/someApp-Swift.h -working-directory /Users/kanishka/Desktop/someApp

Comment: Always use the latest beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beta 5 was released yesterday, there is very little point in trying to work around problems with beta 1.